# Cisco Aironet 1830 - disable SSID broadcast?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssid

I recently purchased a Cisco Aironet 1830, I've configured it and it is working great. However I can not for the life of me find out how to disable broadcasting the SSID. Does anyone know a command I can run to disable it? or am I missing something in the GUI?

SYSTEM INFORMATION
MODEL: AIR-AP1832I-B-K9
SOFTWARE VERSION : 8.2.100.0

Comment: correct, my apologizes.

Answer (score 0):

```
AP(config)#interface dot11Radio0
AP(config-if)#ssid
AP(config-if-ssid)#no guest-mode
```

That should do the trick. As far as the GUI there should be an SSID manager page and unchecking guest mode would do the same thing.

Comment: I tried running the commands you suggested; however the AP is not letting me get into "config", if I run a "config ?" it only lists "boot Set boot parameters". Also as you stated above in the GUI, there is no section for SSID Management, I'm running the Cisco Mobility Express software. Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

(Cisco Controller) config>wlan broadcast-ssid disable (number of wlan) 
wlan must be disable before apply